How to install ibm_db nodejs package for MAC M1/M2chips?
I had trouble installing ibm_db package using node v20.
I have noticed we need x64 version of nodejs instead of arm64,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Solution:
Uninstall any node/nvm packages installed earlier.
Terminal commands:
Step:1
switch terminal to x64 architecture
arch -x86_64 zsh
Step:2
install nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash
step:3
set env props
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
Step:4
install node
nvm install 20
Step5:
verify node architecture version - It should return : x64
node -p "process.arch"

Latest release of ibm_db package has fixed this issue and you can install it simply using npm install ibm_db@3.3.0 command. Now, ibm_db works with arm64 version of nodejs on MacOS M1 Chip system. Thanks.
